# Set multiple cookies in Apache

Tags: apache, cookies, mod-headers

I'm trying to set two cookies in Apache (2.2), using mod_header, like so:

```
Header set Set-Cookie "poodle=noodle;path=/;Secure;HttpOnly;Expires=Wed, Jan 01 2020 2:02:02 GMT"
Header set Set-Cookie "tweedle=puddle;path=/;Secure;HttpOnly;Expires=Wed, Jan 01 2020 2:02:02 GMT"
```

But only the last cookie is being sent to the browser.  I've done some searching, but only found people having this problem with no solution.  I've tried combining them into one:

```
Header set Set-Cookie "poodle=noodle;tweedle=puddle;path=/;Secure;HttpOnly;Expires=Wed, Jan 01 2020 2:02:02 GMT"
```

Same problem.  Do I need to use "Header append" instead?  Any examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) with the [cookie flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_co)  the syntax is:

```
 [CO=NAME:VALUE:DOMAIN:lifetime:path:secure:httponly]
```

So you want something similar to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* -  [CO=poodle:noodle:example.com:0:/:true:true]
RewriteRule .* -  [CO=tweedle:puddle:example.com:0:/:true:true]
```

Comment: Works great, thanks.  I never noticed the [CO] section of the docs for mod_rewrite until now.

Answer (score 10):

According to the Apache manual http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header you should use `append`:

```
Header append Set-Cookie "poodle=noodle;path=/;Secure;HttpOnly;Expires=Wed, Jan 01 2020 2:02:02 GMT"
Header append Set-Cookie "tweedle=puddle;path=/;Secure;HttpOnly;Expires=Wed, Jan 01 2020 2:02:02 GMT"
```

or according to HTTP use comma to separate multiple values:

```
Header append Set-Cookie "poodle=noodle;path=/;Secure;HttpOnly;Expires=Wed, Jan 01 2020 2:02:02 GMT, tweedle=puddle;path=/;Secure;HttpOnly;Expires=Wed, Jan 01 2020 2:02:02 GMT"
```

or use `Header add` if you want avoid comma separated cookies in one header to follow suggestions in RFC 6265 section 3 (as noted by @SteveC):

```
Header add Set-Cookie "poodle=noodle;path=/;Secure;HttpOnly;Expires=Wed, Jan 01 2020 2:02:02 GMT"
Header add Set-Cookie "tweedle=puddle;path=/;Secure;HttpOnly;Expires=Wed, Jan 01 2020 2:02:02 GMT"
```

Comment: Do you hardcode the expires date on your Set-Cookie entry? How do you get that to be dynamic?

Comment: you can use max-age attribute (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265) with seconds, or you do some math with the request time ... but i do not kow how.

Comment: max-age doesn't work with IE11 or earlier: mrcoles.com/blog/cookies-max-age-vs-expires/

Comment: By the way, I asked how to set the expires dynamically in the Set-Cookie entry here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29549963/1601989

Comment: You cannot use `Header append Set-Cookie` because this will just append the cookie value to any existing `Set-Cookie` header with a comma. This is forbidden by RFC6265.

Comment: @SteveC, it is only "should not" and not forbidden - if your referring to section 3 of RFC6265, but you can use "Header add" instead of "append" for Set-Cookie

Comment: `Header add` worked for me but the first two ways didn't work