# apache How to use "Header set Set-Cookie expires=<date>" dynamically

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, cookies, mod-headers

I am using apache as a load balancer and reverse proxy.
For session stickiness I am creating a cookie with the route of the node.

```
Header set Set-Cookie "h=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/; domain=.domain.com" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
```

**How do I set the `expires` value in the cookie to be X minutes from when the request comes in?**

The documentation for [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html) Doesn't even cover `Set-Cookie` in detail so there is no info there on a dynamic syntax to use for `expires`.

I tried setting the `max-age` but unfortunatelly [max-age doesn't work with IE 11](http://mrcoles.com/blog/cookies-max-age-vs-expires/) and lots of our customers use it.

The docs for [mod_rewrite cookie](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_co) do cover how to set a lifetime in the cookie so I can get it to work using this ugly mod_rewrite hack but I had to do one rule per route since it didn't work inside my `<Proxy balancer://my_cluster>` section:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} h=.1 [NC]
RewriteRule . -  [CO=h:.1:.domain.com:30:/]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} h=.2 [NC]
RewriteRule . -  [CO=h:.2:.domain.com:30:/]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} h=.3 [NC]
RewriteRule . -  [CO=h:.3:.domain.com:30:/]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} h=.4 [NC]
RewriteRule . -  [CO=h:.4:.domain.com:30:/]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} h=.5 [NC]
RewriteRule . -  [CO=h:.5:.domain.com:30:/]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} h=.6 [NC]
RewriteRule . -  [CO=h:.6:.domain.com:30:/]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} h=.7 [NC]
RewriteRule . -  [CO=h:.7:.domain.com:30:/]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} h=.8 [NC]
RewriteRule . -  [CO=h:.8:.domain.com:30:/]
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish with `Header set Set-Cookie`? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could keep your idea with a generic rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} h=\.([1-8]) [NC]
RewriteRule . - [CO=h:.%1:.domain.com:30:/]
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the rule. I didn't dig more into making that part generic because I want to be able to accomplish it with `Header set Set-Cookie`, otherwise I am setting a cookie without a timeout to right after rewrite it. This is what I am using for now though.

Comment: I'm not aware of another way of doing it, except with `Header` and this code. Is there a particular reason you only want to achieve it with `Header` ? Personally, i would have done it as i answered. Maybe you could describe what's the context and why you have to do it, then we could see if it exists a better option

Comment: Just because I am setting the cookie and then rewriting it. That seems rather wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the paypal sites cookie and found they set the cookie time to past year -(01 -01-1970). The reason behind this could be to stop reuse of cookies.